# Pivoting results from CTE in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a large SQL statements(PostgreSQL version 11) with many CTE's, i want to use the results from an intermediary CTE to create a PIVOTed set of results and join it with other CTE.

Below is a small part of my query and the CTE "previous_months_actual_sales" is the one i need to PIVOT.

```
,last_24 as
(
    SELECT l_24m::DATE + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,24)) as last_24m
 FROM last_24_month_start LIMIT 24
)
,previous_months_actual_sales as
(
    SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at,'YYYY-MM') as dates
    ,b.code,SUM(quantity) as qty  
FROM base b
INNER JOIN products_sold  ps ON ps.code=b.code 
WHERE TO_CHAR(created_at,'YYYY-MM')
IN(SELECT TO_CHAR(last_24m,'YYYY-MM') FROM last_24)
GROUP BY b.code,TO_CHAR(created_at,'YYYY-MM')
)
SELECT * FROM previous_months_actual_sales
```

The results of this CTE "previous_months_actual_sales" is shown below,

```
dates       code        qty
"2018-04"   "0009"      23
"2018-05"   "0009"      77
"2018-06"   "0008"      44
"2018-07"   "0008"      1
"2018-08"   "0009"      89
```

The expected output based on the above result is,

```
code.     2018-04.    2018-05.     2018-06.    2018-07.   2018-08
"0009".     23         77                                   89
"0008".                               44          1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?